# Create no. of elements in an array equivalent to an user's input in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create an array using jquery where the no. of elements in it depends on a number enter by an user. For example; If an user enters 5 then the array should contain 5 elements as 0,1,2,3,4.

This is what I have been trying so far ....

```
function loadPage(id, id2, id3){
    var hs= document.getElementById(id).value;
    var selected= document.getElementById(id2).value;
    var distid = document.getElementById(id3).value;
    var ui = hs+selected;
    alert(ui);

    var res;
    var valArray = [];

    $.ajax({
             type:"POST",
             url:"DynaServlet",
             data:{ui:ui},
             datatype: "text",
             success:function(result){

                 res = result;
                 alert(res);
                     valArray.push(res);
             alert(valArray[0] + "array");

             }     
    });
```

The loadPage() appends ids of two elements which forms a unique id and through a java servlet a property file is been searched and the id's corresponding value is received. Depending on this value I want to create an array with no. of elements equivalent to the value received.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: I have updated my codes, please check...

Comment: so are you calling `loadPage` 5 times?  If so, you need to move `var valArray = [];` outside of that function so it becomes a global variable.  Right now it is scoped to `loadPage`, and it will lose all previous values after the function ends.  If this is not the case, we need more information on where the number of values entered is being returned.  E.g., are you returning the 5 values as `result` in the success method?  Though I think the scope is the biggest issue for you ATM.

Comment: No, I am not calling the loadPage() 5 times. Its like on click of a button the loadPage() gets activated, and suppose the button's id is the id we create using "ui".This id is sent and its corresponding value is returned as "result". Using this value the array needs to be create. Yes, the

Comment: Yes, the valArray = []; is scoped to loadPage.